# Windows service in starting state and can not make it in running state

Tags: windows-services

I developed a windows service in C#. I followed some existing tutorials from google. In service.cs class the constructor is only holding the InitializeComponent() method. In OnStart() method I have written some code to open a port using TCPClient to connect via tcp connection to some other client. In that OnStart() method I am receiving a response from client using AcceptTcpClient() method and forwarding to an another class to process the client's response and send it back to the client. I maintained the coding fashion in ServiceInstaller and ServiceProcessInstaller and to start the service automatically adding up the event handler named AfterInstall and Commited. As I am installing the service, in service.msc it is showing service status as starting but the service is working as it should. Why the status is not showing running state?

Comment: If your code is entirely inside OnStart() you might want to try moving it out; the service status may not change to Running until OnStart() has returned. Can you refactor it into eg. run in another thread?

Comment: I couldn't get you point. And OnStart is a void method. So what to return. I am writing only the essential code in OnStart() like:

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1257396/Windows-service-in-starting-state-and-can-not-make

Comment: check this link, The coding style is here

Comment: What you need to return from `OnStart` is *control of the thread that's running it*. It's not your thread.

Comment: @T2PS
Thank You for the advice, but I am new in windows service so can you please suggest me how to work with OnStart() method, so that the will be in the running status

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ; Can you please elaborate the scenario. I am new with windows service

Comment: I can't think of many other ways to express this. There's some other code (in the framework) that's effectively got `yourService.OnStart(args); serviceControlManager.ReportServiceHasFinishedStarting();`. It can't run that second line of code until `OnStart` returns, so you can't run e.g. an endless `while` loop inside it (or wait for clients to connect, etc). You need to *start things running* (create other threads, timers, etc) and then return.